# How to achieve cucumber parallel execution using cucumber tags?

Tags: parallel-processing, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I am trying to achieve parallel execution using cucumber tags. I have attached my feature file below and instead of using multiple feature files I am trying to achieve parallel execution of my scenario's using cucumber tags `@au,@nl, @nz`

I am aware we can achieve parallel execution using feature file but I would like to execute my tags based on locale in parallel using cucumber tags.Each tag have dependent test with existing customer.

**Note : I am using serenity BDD**

```
 1. browser 1: au (first execute new user, second execution for existing user )
 2. browser 2: nl (first execute new user, second execution for existing user )
 3. browser 3: nz (first execute new user, second execution for existing user )
```

**sample.feature**

```
 @au  @smoke
  Scenario: A new user can place a order
    Given the user is on homepage
    When the user perform checkout
    Then order confirmation page is display
    
  @au  @smoke
  Scenario: A new user can place a order
    Given the existing user is on homepage
    When the existing user perform checkout
    Then order confirmation page is display
    
  @nl  @smoke
  Scenario: A new user can place a order
    Given the user is on homepage
    When the user perform checkout
    Then order confirmation page is display
    
  @nl  @smoke
  Scenario: A new user can place a order
    Given the existing user is on homepage
    When the existing user perform checkout
    Then order confirmation page is display
    
    
  @nz  @smoke
  Scenario: A new user can place a order
    Given the user is on homepage
    When the user perform checkout
    Then order confirmation page is display
    
  @nz  @smoke
  Scenario: A new user can place a order
    Given the existing user is on homepage
    When the existing user perform checkout
    Then order confirmation page is display
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cucumber 4 & above, you can do this way

```
import io.cucumber.core.cli.main

public class MyRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main.run(new String[]{
        "--threads", "3",
        "-t", "@au and @nz",
        "-g", "com.your.glue",
        "src/test/resources/features/",
      }, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
  }
}
```

Note :

1. This works for me with cucumber 6.1.0.
2. You can even use testNG instead of main method.
3. You'll need to take care of webdriver thread safety

Comment: I have tried above solution but unfortunately it's not working for me, i am using serenity bdd net.serenity-bdd:serenity-cucumber:1.9.7